# Merge multiple databases into one

Tags: sql, database, merge, schema, composite-primary-key

I have a desktop app that clients are using at the moment and each client has access to their own local network database. 
My manager has decided that its best to merge these databases and only have one. All clients would then access that one database through a webservice that sits on the cloud. I would like to weight the pros and cons before we go ahead with this decision.
The one option we have is to have a ClientID in each of the tables which will result in each table having a composite key .

I have heard that another option would be to use schemas .Please advise how the schema way would work and is this the best way in comparison to having a composite key in each table.
Thank you.

Comment: There are pretty large security implications here which will likely require addendums to your client contracts before you even start a technical implementation. To comment on your question, though, you can tie user accounts to schemas much more cleanly than a row ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a seriously difficult and time consuming task. You will need to have extensive regression tests already built because the risk of things breaking is huge.

Let me tell you a story of a client that had a separate database on a separate suerver that got merged with another database that contained many clients. It took several months to make all the changes to convert the data. Everything looked good and it was pushed to prod. Unfortunately the developer missed one place where client id needed to be referenced (It usually wasn't in the old code since they were the only client on the server). The first day in production a process that sent out emails, sent client proprietary data not only to the client sales reps but to the sales reps of many of their competitors. Of all the places that the change could have been missed, this was the worst possible one. It not only harmed our relationship with the first client but with all the clients that got some other client's info by mistake.

There is also the problem of migrating the data, the project for that alone (without the code changes the application will need) will take months and then you have consider that the clients will be adding data as you go and the final push may run into unexpected hiccups due to new data. You may also have to turn off the odl system for at least a weekend to do the production change.

Using schemas won't make it any easier as you will then have to adjust the code to hit the correct schema per client. And when you change somethign you wil have to change it for each individual schema, so it tends to make the database much more difficult to maintain.

While I am a great fan of having multiple clients in one database, when you didn't start out that way, it is extremely risky and expensive to change. I would not do it al all unless I had these things:

```
Code in source control
Extensive Unit and regression tests
Separate dev, QA and prod environments
A process for client UAT testing
Extensive knowledge of how cloud computing and webservices works (everyone I know who has moved stuff to the cloud has had some real gotchas)
A QA department
Six months to one year time frame for the project
At least one senior data analyst on the team.
```